# Скролл к концу содержимого элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `<li id="comment55">много контента</li>`.
Как прокрутить страницу к концу контента `comment55`?

Comment: Отступ от верха до элемента + его высота?

Comment: @Other получается что так.

Comment: А чего тогда спрашивать?

Comment: @Other наверное потому что я неплохо знаю php но очень плохо знаю js по этому и задаю тут такие вопросы :)

Comment: Вам нужен скролл по клику на элемент?

Comment: Можно еще воспользоваться `.scrollTo()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$("#scrollBtn").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#bigBlock").offset().top + $("#bigBlock").height() + 2
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#bigBlock{
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
#scrollBtn{
  position: fixed;
  right: 1%; top: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='scrollBtn' value='Скролл' />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis iste tempora perspiciatis amet sequi tenetur labore consequuntur explicabo architecto, officia voluptate autem excepturi ex iure dolore dolor, voluptates facilis beatae quidem quis esse nulla adipisci. Recusandae dicta excepturi unde porro, id est consequuntur nostrum aliquid modi accusantium aut officia perspiciatis magnam optio veniam sapiente vitae minima voluptate necessitatibus. Voluptatibus voluptatem laudantium eaque, numquam itaque laborum, consectetur repellendus rem cum recusandae pariatur laboriosam reiciendis est unde obcaecati velit nostrum sequi quaerat doloremque dignissimos sapiente a! Voluptates consectetur fuga possimus sed necessitatibus ut blanditiis temporibus, aspernatur expedita officia facere praesentium ipsum soluta numquam veniam, eligendi illum dolores laborum, quaerat magni voluptatum inventore. Quasi quia doloremque doloribus amet expedita quis beatae minus. Quae id nihil veritatis soluta aliquid eaque beatae suscipit voluptates delectus voluptatum corporis, itaque dolorum illo eum odio! Nostrum eum, est ipsa laudantium, ea doloribus similique repellendus voluptatem expedita temporibus quo dolor nesciunt mollitia eos minima praesentium amet aliquid! Eaque minima cupiditate illo laboriosam ipsum facere distinctio aliquid, adipisci neque magnam ut ullam culpa delectus, labore suscipit maiores nemo commodi deleniti, possimus fugit non voluptate autem pariatur alias. Quae quisquam accusantium placeat eligendi nihil necessitatibus iure, commodi incidunt impedit facere totam!
<div id="bigBlock">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque iusto maxime ad, rerum magnam tenetur, temporibus recusandae illum! Aliquam placeat consectetur itaque expedita incidunt quas fugit, tempore natus suscipit sed dolore officiis perferendis. Eligendi praesentium quidem, libero ducimus illum natus laudantium accusantium neque voluptates sint architecto, aliquid dolores mollitia consequatur deleniti fuga totam optio reiciendis. Iure recusandae at maxime iusto magni numquam, placeat obcaecati laborum enim tempore officia optio. Voluptatibus tempora illo eaque voluptate quis rem dolor molestiae recusandae aliquam aspernatur quae praesentium porro quod pariatur fugiat, debitis placeat neque repellat. Eligendi mollitia provident eos perspiciatis aliquam quidem ad nostrum perferendis repellat expedita facilis temporibus dolor aut totam excepturi asperiores autem dolorem suscipit soluta neque quo incidunt, eveniet amet? Sequi ea, magnam quam et vitae quae nemo sunt delectus soluta, distinctio voluptatem consequuntur nulla nobis architecto ducimus. Eius suscipit inventore aut consectetur sequi unde sunt voluptatibus impedit porro, soluta animi? Quisquam asperiores incidunt numquam ea vero minus dolorem. Sint praesentium omnis dignissimos libero tempora quidem ipsum autem possimus quos adipisci officiis hic eos incidunt debitis, architecto impedit error provident molestiae voluptates culpa quas dolorum quam, est ex fugiat. Nemo adipisci magni harum neque libero debitis quis nesciunt architecto illo non. Commodi aut sunt distinctio quo pariatur iusto est excepturi ducimus, non unde asperiores voluptatibus libero dolor tempore debitis rerum iure aliquam labore? Nesciunt a, quos autem sint blanditiis impedit maxime rerum provident. Dignissimos pariatur id, modi tempore! Eius cumque laborum voluptas, nesciunt, culpa tenetur, laboriosam exercitationem labore aliquid, eaque doloribus. Suscipit explicabo totam blanditiis quis doloribus praesentium repudiandae, obcaecati corporis. Veritatis fugiat dolorem, iusto dolorum ipsam accusantium debitis perferendis tempore, voluptate atque quibusdam accusamus. Dolore dolor, accusantium dicta sint recusandae, nisi? Commodi deserunt quod est sit, facere eum magnam rerum officia atque distinctio doloremque, unde possimus. Sed sit, aliquam quibusdam aliquid atque, itaque molestias aut aspernatur natus fuga exercitationem optio nisi modi accusantium enim beatae, expedita. Dolorem ullam recusandae est nam repellendus unde deleniti optio iusto sit saepe, nulla, voluptates earum omnis perspiciatis cumque architecto consequatur sapiente distinctio eveniet incidunt quidem mollitia in! Omnis repudiandae cupiditate, facilis eligendi veniam debitis eaque aliquam commodi fuga nesciunt architecto maxime tempore dolorem nostrum, earum odit quod repellat ut quaerat magnam ad esse ex et modi. Sunt maxime alias officiis, placeat dolorem nisi libero quis ad, aliquam sit laborum veritatis vitae eos inventore blanditiis quisquam, voluptate? Iure obcaecati, ipsam repudiandae, dolorem amet eligendi neque quod fuga autem porro at, saepe sint unde tenetur! Numquam quam consectetur quas adipisci veniam dolores molestiae porro natus sit inventore fugit animi ad modi cumque, repellat sed iusto deleniti, nostrum unde voluptate voluptatem sunt vel? Sunt maiores nostrum id doloremque vero assumenda laboriosam dolorem placeat optio, quia porro sed aspernatur at perspiciatis quaerat dolore earum soluta unde nemo magni. Sunt eius eaque sint dolorum a quo minus numquam dolores, quod similique soluta tempore delectus cumque, et voluptatum unde nemo earum ipsum pariatur accusamus rerum ad? Praesentium consectetur, ab nostrum dicta saepe, quis quia esse totam quam facere consequuntur doloremque.</div>
<br /><div>Сюда хотел?</div><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, vitae possimus, asperiores repellendus saepe qui dolorum dolores fuga nemo nesciunt veniam porro sint dicta sed iure culpa, accusantium ut reiciendis quidem consequuntur expedita. Quis minima debitis incidunt et quas molestias cupiditate sed, aut fuga saepe numquam asperiores quidem, doloribus delectus quod suscipit, porro vero. Accusantium ab pariatur aut quos recusandae doloremque asperiores facilis aliquam adipisci commodi, quam enim impedit neque, debitis, eos iusto officia eligendi modi inventore dicta magnam animi iste. Omnis non nisi dicta ex hic deleniti maiores laudantium placeat voluptate doloribus doloremque dignissimos quis vitae unde sint illo libero ipsa nihil, qui mollitia recusandae rerum fuga eaque temporibus atque. Non suscipit iusto consequatur velit soluta exercitationem quasi explicabo a nam aliquam rerum, corporis impedit temporibus officiis nisi dignissimos laborum beatae autem deleniti ullam sequi voluptates odio. Autem, mollitia. Laudantium doloremque, ut, dolor necessitatibus illo provident natus pariatur ad vel sequi ipsum nobis quaerat assumenda eum recusandae. Velit beatae perferendis at iure sit, quas saepe, dolore iusto deleniti. Aut eaque atque, quidem velit, optio nesciunt ratione ea distinctio repellat ipsa saepe modi commodi ipsam! Dignissimos ullam possimus a, et earum, dolorum quod libero consequuntur ipsa rem nostrum dolore iste, aliquid aliquam! Tenetur necessitatibus eius labore vitae repellendus laboriosam doloribus! Dicta dignissimos rerum mollitia facere aut asperiores adipisci eius nisi unde, sed repellat illo cupiditate excepturi enim omnis hic repudiandae quas, reiciendis in magni harum praesentium iure itaque ullam! Minima ducimus maxime suscipit quae nihil tempora tenetur officia debitis eos veritatis id, beatae quasi cumque dicta, dolorem in pariatur temporibus aspernatur aliquid earum. Quo soluta perferendis non quibusdam commodi rem ea? Eligendi aliquam veniam impedit fugit sit aspernatur sunt amet incidunt maxime debitis tenetur, quasi ipsam dolor commodi rem totam in adipisci dicta omnis explicabo quod, nam! Suscipit nemo repellendus iste modi officia, libero explicabo. Repellendus aliquid velit, odio explicabo nostrum earum blanditiis asperiores modi saepe ea, pariatur quos suscipit fugiat in quod laudantium nisi nemo? Officia numquam dignissimos quasi mollitia, aliquam quibusdam libero laudantium enim sit hic, doloremque adipisci eius, et laboriosam eos animi veniam dolores ducimus fugit quae. Quisquam, reiciendis earum ab nam molestiae. Alias assumenda in asperiores quisquam, cupiditate autem, debitis ab dicta illo quaerat suscipit voluptatibus, enim sed corporis? Animi accusamus inventore ipsam commodi unde similique voluptatibus doloribus omnis. Veniam, molestiae eos, blanditiis tenetur accusantium facilis deserunt numquam, aspernatur debitis architecto odio corporis dolorum incidunt facere provident quidem. Suscipit placeat in repellat alias quidem odit consequuntur vero assumenda. Mollitia dolores officia repellendus modi doloribus, voluptate neque blanditiis eos quas facilis numquam ut repudiandae obcaecati ea amet, consectetur nam nisi perspiciatis, saepe pariatur? Quam distinctio molestiae iste autem officia, repellendus, explicabo, similique nobis vitae quis non saepe sapiente inventore enim sequi eius delectus suscipit consequatur cupiditate nostrum quo placeat. Hic accusamus vitae dolore animi nostrum assumenda obcaecati repellat doloribus perspiciatis ut atque, voluptates beatae quam itaque minima non eveniet ea adipisci provident similique molestiae, eum aperiam accusantium. Dolores aspernatur nemo similique, blanditiis quas impedit sequi ipsa doloribus!
```